# What's the most performant way to construct a left-padded with NULL fixed length character array in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, low-level

If you have something like:

```
char buf[10];
```

and need to create a function like:

```
void pad(char* dest, const char* src, size_t destlen, size_t srclen);
```

so `pad(dest, "hello", 10, 5)` will result in `"hello\0\0\0\0\0"`

I'm not sure what the most efficient way of doing this is using gcc 4.x:

`snprintf` then `bzero`?

`operator<<` with `setfill` and friends then `memcpy`?

Performance is important for this particular case.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I'm not sure what the most efficient way of doing this is."  Try both and see which one is faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `memcpy` and `memset` like

```
void pad(char* dest, const char* src, size_t destlen, size_t srclen)
{
    memcpy(dest, src, srclen);
    memset(dest+srclen, '\0', dstlen - srclen);
}
```

of course you should also check that you can fit `src` into `dst`

Comment: Thanks, I will benchmark these to be sure, but I agree that this would be the most straightforward way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 3):

How about `memcpy` followed by `memset`?

```
void pad(char* dest, const char* src, size_t destlen, size_t srclen)
{
    memcpy(dest, src, srclen);
    memset(dest + srclen, 0, destlen - srclen);
}
```

Comment: you typed it 50sec faster than me :D